# List Driven, Cascading, Multi-Choice form fields

Tags: 2013, custom-form, spservices, choice-field, multi-select

I am looking to be able to select multiple values like this.

- Circle

  - Red
  - Blue
- Triangle

  - Green
  - Blue
- Square

  - Yellow
  - Green
  - Red
  - Blue

So I can have a Circle-Blue; Square-Yellow; Square-Green; as the returned selections. All based off of a list or two for easy adding or editing in the future. Currently I have a list of Shapes that has a lookup field from the List of Colors all acting as a lookup to my Toys list.

Is there a way to do this OOTB that I am unaware of or is there a way to get SPServices, Select2, or some other addon to get this to work?

Comment: Why not use managed metadata instead. Works great for this scenario.

Comment: @MagnusDanielson An example would be great.